# I need to Combine two lists that have 1 similar column and a second unique column

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I'm trying to phrase this to be as clear as possible.

Here is my scenario : I have two data sets.

Dataset1:

```
Individual_id        
Code 1
```

Dataset2 :

```
Individual_id
Code 2
```

The values in `individual_ID` are unique to each dataset, meaning that neither list has a duplicated individual_id so a typical join isnt possible (I dont think so anyways)

What I need my final dataset to look like is this:

```
Individual_ID   Code1     Code 2
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: This is actually impossible to answer without data sample and expected output

Comment: Can an individual have more than one code in each table?  Are the same individuals in both tables?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Can you supply a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) for your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT Individual_id, Code1, NULL Code2 FROM dataset1
UNION ALL
SELECT Individual_id, NULL, Code2 FROM dataset2
```

`UNION ALL` combines the recordsets returns by both queries. Both resultset must return the same columns, so you need to want to the unavailable column in each resultset with `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

you can only make cross-join if datasets does not have relationship between them

```
selec t1.individual_id, Code1, Code2
from t1
cross join t2
```

but please note that cross-join multiplies results by `m x n` where m is number of records returned from `t1` and `n` is number of records returned from `t2`

or

if your intention is to merge two datasets into one then,

```
select Individual_id, Max(Code1) Code1, Max(Code2) Code2 From
(
    SELECT Individual_id, Code1, NULL Code2 FROM dataset1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Individual_id, NULL, Code2 FROM dataset2
) t
Group by Individual_id
```